# RelativeLayout screenshot including mapFragment saves black image

Tags: java, android

I have a RelativeLayout view which includes some TextViews and a map fragment. I want to take a screenshot of the whole screen (including the map as displayed and the text) and save it. Everything working as expected but the view with the map shows a black image. How is this possible?

I've also tried with some delay interval to be sure the map is fully loaded but didn't worked.

```
    Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();
    createDirectoryAndSaveFile(bitmap,intent.getStringExtra("TEST"));

    public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
    View rootView = findViewById(R.id.relative_layout);
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }

    private void createDirectoryAndSaveFile(Bitmap bitmap, String name) {

    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/Test");

    if (!folder.exists()) {
    File screenshoDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test/");
    screenshoDir.mkdirs();
    }
    File file = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Test/"), name);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.getPath()}, new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```